# Gradle projects depending on artifacts created by sibling projects

Tags: dependencies, gradle, siblings

I have this Gradle setup with four projects, a parent with three children, where a Java Servlet JSON 'backend' is built into a war-file, and then a static HTML5 'frontend' consuming this is built into a zip. Both these "installs" their artifcats to the local maven repo.

**The third sibling project 'merger' depends on these two artifacts, to build a "merged" war by simply "zipping them together".**

However, once I had this up and running as intended, I obviously had to *test the bootstrap-scenario by deleting the artifacts from the local repo.*

Now I suddenly get "Artifact 'no.company:frontend:1.0-SNAPSHOT@zip' not found".

Is it not possible to depend on artifacts which **will be produced** by the current build?

*Edit:*

Based on another idea (and the reply from Peter discouraging this Maven logic), this version looks promising, not traversing Maven (note: it works!):

```
// ## From frontend's build.gradle:
task zipFrontend(dependsOn: 'buildFrontend',  type: Zip) {
    from ('dist/')
}

// ## From backend's build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'war'

// ## From merger's build.gradle:
task mergeFrontAndBack(dependsOn: [':backend:war', 
                                   ':frontend:zipFrontend'], type: War) {
    from zipTree(project(':frontend').tasks['zipFrontend'].archivePath)
    from zipTree(project(':backend').tasks['war'].archivePath)
    destinationDir(buildDir)
}
```

*Edit 2:*

Based upon Peter's comment about not reaching into siblings' project structure and his concrete suggestions, here's the resulting piece (note: it works!):

```
// ## From frontend's build.gradle:
task zipFrontend(dependsOn: 'buildFrontend',  type: Zip) {
    from ('dist/')
}
configurations { zip }
artifacts { zip zipFrontend }

// ## From backend's build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'war'
configurations { jsonOnlyWar }
artifacts { jsonOnlyWar war }

// ## From merger's build.gradle:
configurations { merge }
dependencies {
    merge project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'jsonOnlyWar')
    merge project(path: ':frontend', configuration: 'zip')
}
task mergeFrontAndBack(dependsOn: configurations.merge, type: War) {
    from { configurations.merge.collect { zipTree(it) } }
    destinationDir(buildDir)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The local Maven repository (and Gradle's `install` task) should only be used when exchanging artifacts with Maven builds. It's not meant to be used for exchanging artifacts between projects of a Gradle build, and installing into the local Maven repository won't happen automatically.

Instead, `merger` needs to declare *project dependencies* on the other two projects. For example:

```
configurations {
     merge
}

dependencies {
    merge project(":frontend"), project(":backend")
}

task merge(type: Zip) {
    from { configurations.merge.collect { zipTree(it) } }
}
```

This assumes that `frontend` and `backend` correctly declare their artifacts. (This may happen automatically, for example if the `war` plugin is used.)

You'll find much more on this in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), in particular the multi-project builds chapter.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, because this was how I did it with Maven (and I do install the artifacts to local Maven repo - this works!). However, I've tried the project dependency route you here suggest, but then I only get the JAR from the java-war-project (not the war), and not the zip from the static HTML-files project at all. Also, if I do the merge-task you define, won't I also merge in all the jar's from the java-war project? See, I only want the WAR-structure merged with the ZIP file of static HTML files (the resulting beast is servlet-container-deployable as a proper war due to the nature of war's).

Comment: Also - now I am trying another route: In the merger-project, I simply define a type:War task, which sets from-properties to the output of the "war" task in backend, and on the "zipFrontend" task of frontend. Is this possible? How? The tasks-property doesn't seem to hold sibling references?

Comment: Reaching out into the project model of other projects is discouraged. Instead, declare the necessary artifacts for the other two projects, e.g. `configurations { zip }; artifacts { zip taskThatProducesZip }`. Then adapt the project dependencies (e.g. `dependencies { merge project(path: ":frontend", configuration: "zip") }`.

Comment: Excellent, this approach seems nice! How do I now get hold of the war from the 'backend' project with the same logic? There is already a war-task, since I apply the war plugin. But apparently that is not a "configuration", and I have problems defining it as such.

Comment: Should work exactly the same as my code for "frontend" above.

Comment: What I just realized when reading that, was that I could maybe hack it. Because this doesn't cut it: configurations { war }; artifacts { war war } and then dependencies { merge project(path: ":backend", configuration: "war") } (I actually expected the "war" to be an "implicit configuration", so that only the dependency would be needed..). But then I tried configurations { theWar }; artifacts { theWar war } and dep on "theWar", and this works! The question is updated with the results.

Comment: It's safer to make` mergeFrontAndBack` a `Zip` task, as otherwise you might end up with some duplicated `War` behavior (e.g. duplicated descriptors). Another improvement is to make `mergeFrontAndBack` depend on `configurations.merge`, rather than on individual tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Using this post and ideas from elsewhere I made a github project - https://github.com/istomisgood/WarNode