# Building and deploying a dependency android Gradle project

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have 3 projects. A, B and C
B is dependent on A
C is dependent on B

(A and B are anroid library projects)

I want to build them using gradle so that:

project A will be compiled than deployed to my .m2 repository 
project B then will be compiled using A as a dependency from my local .m2 and will be deployed to my .m2 repository
project C will then be compiled using B and A as dependencies from my local .m2 and then be deployed to .m2 as well

currently i haven't managed to do so and im mostly facing conflicts with the maven plugin and com.android.library plugin

(i can not put all of them in the same gradle build, but have one gradle build file for each of them - i got many other modules like C, C2, C3 etc..)

any assistance will be appreciated

thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle projects depending on artifacts created by sibling projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875576/gradle-projects-depending-on-artifacts-created-by-sibling-projects)